# Intermolecular forces between polyatomic ions and water

Tags: intermolecular-forces

I was wondering what kind of intermoleuclar attraction exists between nitrate ion $\ce{NO3-}$ and $\ce{H2O}$?
Is it ion-dipole attraction or is it hydrogen bonding? Since there is nitrogen and oxygen, are both molecules highly electronegtive? Does each oxygen on the $\ce{NO3-}$ attract one water each?

Comment: Well, it's pretty obvious there's hydrogen bonding. Average number number of h-bonds per oxygen isn't constant.

Comment: It's a good question. I would start by drawing resonance forms. Then again bonding with the solvent probably stabilizes individual forms (causes resonance to break down)?

Comment: All mentioned forms take part. Ion-dipole interaction on longer distance, bond dipole-dipole interactions at shorter distance and finally hydrogen bonding.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I had a deeper look into the hydration of nitrate ions and some associated papers. The oxygen with its negative charge is the hydrogen bond acceptor. 

Following on Poutnik's answer, how does ion-dipole interaction and hydrogen bonding exist at the same time?  From my understanding ion-dipole is the electrostatic interaction between and ion and a charged dipole; In this case,  nitrate ion and the partially positive hydrogen in water.